# How to use load() function in pyxel in conjunction with a .pyxel resource file?

Tags: python-3.x, pyxel

I'm trying to use pyxel for a school project, but when I attempt to use the load() function to load my resource file sprites.pyxel, as well as when I made a test file which removed every other unneccesary aspect except resource file loading, it threw a NameError involving the load() function, saying that sprites was not defined. I have tried removing the .pyxel filetype in the code, but to no avail. I am also aware that the self argument in the draw() function is unused. sprites.pyxel is in the same directory. Before I opened up an issue on Github, I wanted to know if I was doing something wrong. Here's the test code:

```
import pyxel

class test:
  def __init__(self):
    pyxel.init(16, 16)
    pyxel.run(self.update, self.draw)

  def update(self):
    pass

  def draw(self):
    pyxel.load(sprites.pyxel)
    pyxel.blt(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 16, 14)

test()
```

If it helps, this is on repl.it.

*Images, because I don't have enough reputation

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1YCs.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsNsh.jpg

Comment: SOLVED. The filepath has to be a string.

Answer (score 0):

Im trying init the pyxel edit, but i don't understand the documentation, wheres exactly i run de command `pyxel edit [PYXEL_RESOURCE_FILE]`